# Defaulting non-nullable fields to default type value when loading CSVs in EF Effort

Tags: c#, entity-framework, csv, effort

I'm using a CSV loader to load mock data into Effort. A colleague has checked in a change to one of our database tables (a new non-nullable column) and his gated-check-in failed because Effort was trying to assign a null value when we were expecting the values to be 0.

Short of going back and changing every row in the CSV file, is there a way for us to have Effort populate these non-nullable columns default to the default value for their types?

```
Exception message:Effort.Exceptions.EffortException : An unhandled exception occurred while trying to assign value '[null]' to Property 'TaskQueueId' of type 'System.Int32' during entity initialization for table
```

Comment: What sort of CSV loader are you using? Doesn't it return a collection of rows or materialized objects from rows of CSV? If it does then you can set the column to 0 on those objects/rows.

Comment: It's the Effort.DataLoaders.CsvDataLoader that then gets passed into the ObjectContextFactory.

Answer (score 1):

As in this example on https://entityframework-effort.net/load-data-from-csv:

```
IDataLoader loader = new Effort.DataLoaders.CsvDataLoader(@"D:\CsvFiles")

using (NorthwindEntities ctx = Effort.ObjectContextFactory.CreateTransient(loader))
{
    var products = ctx.Products.ToList();
}
```

You can setup column value when objects are materialsed. Like if we have to set some property on `Product` objects:

```
var products = ctx.Products.ToList();
foreach(var p in products)
{
    p.UnitPrice *=1.2m;
}
```